# How to display pagination with carousel card in MS Teams

Tags: node.js, typescript, botframework

Circle pagination does not display in carousel card. Any suggest for me?

[image]

**nodejs**

```
public buildAttachments(): Attachment[] {
    return [
      this.buildWelcomeCard(),
      this.buildSearchLibrary(),
      this.buildNextLevel(),
    ];
  }

const attachments = cardBuilder.buildAttachments();
const textHeader = `Text Header`;
await context.sendActivity({ text: textHeader, attachmentLayout: AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel, attachments});
```

Comment: Is this your GitHub issue? https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1626

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

The circle pagination you're looking for is only in the mobile app and not the desktop app. If you would like to suggest this as a feature for the desktop app, please feel free to use the Teams feedback forum: https://teamsfeedback.uservoice.com